# hyperref adds extension to href

Tags: hyperref, expl3

I'm creating a simple macro with `\href` in it. But it seems to be kind of tricky, because using `\href` with a parameter does not recognize the link format. It simply adds an unwanted `.pdf` to the link target.

Basically the link

```
https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
```

is automatically changed to

```
https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref.pdf
```

What is causing this behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__pkgcls:n #1 {
    \texorpdfstring{
            \href{https://ctan.org/pkg/#1}{\ttfamily#1}
    }{#1}
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\class}{o m}{% typeset class names
    \__pkgcls:n { #2 }
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\package}{o m}{% typeset package names
    \__pkgcls:n { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \class{scrartcl}\\\package{hyperref}\\\href{https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref}{\ttfamily hyperref}
\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* Here's a screenshot:

[image: wrong extension]

*Update:* The problem seems clearly expl3 related. Using something like

```
\def\pkgcls#1{\texorpdfstring{\href{https://ctan.org/pkg/#1}{\ttfamily #1}}{#1}}
\def\pkg#1{\pkgcls{#1}}
```

produces the correct result.

Comment: I'm on TL17 (fully updated) if it's of interest.

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: @samcarter A simple pdflatex call. That should usually suffice for links, shouldn't it?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue. I think, the error is the `\ExplSyntaxOn` - regime with `:` in the `https` syntax

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I just tried a l2e version, which worked fine. So the error seems to be expl related. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You're right, good hint. Using `\c_colon_str` instead works. Do you want to answer?

Comment: @TeXnician: Try: `\newcommand{\ctanpath}{https://ctan.org/pkg/}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\cs_new:Npn \__pkgcls:n #1 {
    \texorpdfstring{
      \href{\ctanpath#1}{\ttfamily#1}
    }{#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff` ... you will see, it works

Comment: @TeXnician: Provide a self - answer :-P

Comment: @TeXnician: I removed the irrelevant part of your question (the `\listfiles` output) -- it referred to some stupid comment by me, feel free to roll back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the good hint that `:` might not play well in the url (by Christian Hupfer), I modified a bit and using `\c_colon_str` instead of the literal colon solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__pkgcls:n #1 {
    \texorpdfstring{
            \href{https\c_colon_str//ctan.org/pkg/#1}{\ttfamily#1}
    }{#1}
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\class}{o m}{% typeset class names
    \__pkgcls:n { #2 }
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\package}{o m}{% typeset package names
    \__pkgcls:n { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \class{scrartcl}\\\package{hyperref}\\\href{https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref}{\ttfamily hyperref}
\end{document}
```